# GMap.NET for WPF - IsMouseOverMarker is missing

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

In GMap.NET for Windows Forms you can use IsMouseOverMarker in the GMapControl to determine if you've clicked on a marker on the map.

But i'm using GMap.NET for WPF and there i can't find the IsMouseOverMarker function...

So my question is: How can you determine a MouseOverMarker click event in WPF?

Comment: Have you looked into the CustomMarker samples of the project? https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/Demo.WindowsPresentation/CustomMarkers/CustomMarkerRed.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

For GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation mouse events, tooltip, etc. can be solved through the Shape property of GMapMarker (GMapPolygon, GMapRoute)

```
GMapMarker myMarker;
myMarker.Shape.MouseMove + = new MouseEventHandler (..
```

It does work when writing a code, but Shape is a UIElement type and thus allows familiar use.